# How do clients of a distributed blockchain know about consensus?

Tags: blockchain

I have a basic blockchain I wrote to explore and learn more about the technology. The only real world experience I have with them is in a one-to-one transaction from client to server, as a record of transactions. I'm interested in distributed blockchains now.

In its simplest, most theoretical form, how is consensus managed? How do peers know to begin writing transactions on the next block? You have to know when >50% of the entire pool has accepted some last block written. But p2p systems can be essentially unbounded, and you can't trust a third party to handle surety, so how is this accomplished?

edit: I now know roughly how bitcoin handles consensus:

The consensus determines the accepted blockchain. The typical rule of "longest valid chain first" ensures that only one variant is accepted. People may accept a blockchain after any number of confirmations, typically 6 is sufficient to ensure a clear winner.

However, this seems like a slow and least-deliberate method. It ensures that there is a certain amount of wasted work on the part of nodes that happen to be in a part of the network that had a local valid solution at roughly the same time as a generally accepted solution.

Are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I would say the blockchain technology solves only probabilistic consensus. With a certain confidence, the blockchain-network agrees on something.

Viewing blockchain as a distributed system we can say that the **state of blockchain is distributed**: the blockchain is kept as a whole but there are many distributed replicas of local copies. More interestingly, **the operations are distributed**: Writes or reads can happen at different nodes concurrently. Read operations can be done locally at the local copy of the blockchain, but this read can of course be stale if your local copy is not up-to-date, however there is always an incentive for nodes in the blockchain network to keep their local copy up-to-date so that they can complete new transactions when necessary.

Write operations is the tricky part here, that blockchain must solve. As writes happen concurrently in a distributed fashion, blockchain must ensure to avoid inconsistencies such as double spending and somehow reach consensus on the current state. The way blockchain does this is probabilistic, first of all they made it expensive to write to the chain by adding the "puzzle" to be solved, reducing the probability that different distributed writes happen concurrently, but they can still happen, but with lower probability. In addition, as there is an incentive for nodes in the network to keep their state up to date, nodes that received the flooded write operation will validate it and accept that operation into their chain. I think the incentive to always keep the chain up-to-date is key here because that ensures that the chain will make progress. I.e a writer has a clear incentive to keep its chain up-to-date since it will be competing with the "longest-chain-first" principle against other concurrent writers. For non-adversarial miners there is also an incentive to interrupt the current mining, accept a new write-block and restart the mining process, ensuring a sort of liveness in the system.

So blockchain relies on probabilistic consensus, what is the probability then? The probability that two exactly equal branches growing in parallel at the same time is close to 0 assuming that there are not any large group of adversarial nodes taking over the network. With very high probability  one branch will be longer than the other and be accepted and the network reach consensus on that branch and write operations in the shorter branch have to be re-tried. The big concern is of course big adversarial miner groups who might deliberately try to create forks in the blockchain to perform double spending attacks.. but that is only likely to succeed if they get close to 50% of the computational power in the network.

So to conclude: natural branching in blockchain that can happen due to probabilistic reasons of concurrent writes (probability reduced due to the puzzle-solving) will with almost 100% probability converge to a single branch as write operations continue to happen, and the network reaches consensus on a single branch.

> However, this seems like a slow and least-deliberate method. It
>   ensures that there is a certain amount of wasted work on the part of
>   nodes that happen to be in a part of the network that had a local
>   valid solution at roughly the same time as a generally accepted
>   solution.
>
> Are there better alternatives?

Not that I can think of, there would be many more efficient solutions if all peers in the system "were under control" and you could make them follow some protocol and perhaps have a designated leader to tell the order of writes and ensure consensus, but that is not possible in a decentralized open system.

Answer (score 0):

In the permissioned blockchain environment, where the participants are known in advance, client can get cryptographic proof of the consensus (e.g. that it was signed at least by 2/3 of the participants) and to verify it. Usually it can be achieved using threshold signatures.
In the public blockchains, AFAIK, there is no way to do this since the number of participants is unknown/changes all the time.